# How do I activate template10 in vs2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, template10

For some reason I can not activate template10 in my VS2015. I went in tools->Extensions and Updates and searched online for template10, the result is nothing
[image]

So when I create the project, I do not see template 10

[image]

My VS is 2015 Update3

[image]

What could the issue be? Can anyone point me to a download for vsix for VS2015? I saw the download for VS2017 but can not find the one for 2015.

Comment: I'm adding additional info here, rather than replying to the answer.  This is by design;  see https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/issues/1521.  "Right now we support Visual Studio 2017, but we do not support Visual Studio 2015. My goal is to always support only one version. This was a big deal because the VSIX structure changed between 2015 and 2017; the work necessary to support both was unnecessarily arduous, especially for an open source project like this."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jerry-nixon.Template10TemplatePack) says it works with Visual Studio 2017, therefore I would be surprised if it worked with Visual Studio 2015, hence the reason you do not find the download, unfortunately.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for responding and very much appreciated. Yes, I think it does exist in VS2010 as I saw MVA was talking about it. And their demonstration was actually done in VS2015. Unfortunately, I can not find the template anywhere, built in or online..

Comment: @user1205746 The download from the Visual Studio Marketplace suggests exactly this.  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jerry-nixon.Template10TemplatePack.  "* sorry Visual Studio 2017 support removed Visual Studio 2015 support.".  Seems like you will probably have to grab a stale build like 1.1.12 (https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/tree/version_1.1.12_vs2017)

Comment: @user1205746 I believe you, but the fact is, unfortunately, that they do not seem to support it now: "Just open Visual Studio 2017 & search "Template 10" in the Extension Manager. After installing, go File>New>Project and choose a Template 10 project template." That 2017 is not their by accident: https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/

Comment: Thank you both so much for the instructions. So, I guess they no longer support template10 for VS2015. I do have VS2017 so what Claies said makes sense. That is a bummer as I only plan to use VS2017 for testing water only, now I may have to upgrade to VS2017 and use it for production! I wonder if people with VS2015 only would see Template10...